# How to add public ssh keys to private repos?

Tags: github, ssh

I am trying to set up a private GitHub repo which I need to allow two people to see it. They provided me with their public SSH keys.

I've created the repo.
So as I understood I should put their public SSH keys in the deploy key (my-private-repo > settings > deploy keys).
I did it; however, for both SSH keys I got the following error:

![1]: https://ibb.co/PG1HCtB "key is already in use"

They need to be able to clone it as it is for a test.

It is the very first time that I need to give others access to a private repo. I really tried to find an explanation but I could not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to manage their keys at all. They simply need to create GitHub accounts of their own, and add their SSH keys to those accounts, just like any other user. Then you grant *those accounts* access to your project(s).

Comment: Thanks, @JonathonReinhart. Probably I did not get it right. 
If you can please check this https://github.com/pathable/vnext-code-challenge/blob/master/README.md
it is the link of the challenge that I need to do. The only problem is the github, the rest it is fine. Once again thanks for attention